# Compile typescript files in Angular2 with Gulp

Tags: typescript, gulp, angular

The bottom part of this [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) talks about the command **npm run tsc** to compile the app.ts file to app.js.

How can I do the same with **gulp**?

Comment: You can find sample gulp tasks for typescript compiling in the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33166257/gulp-watch-quells-typescript-errors/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "[gulp-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript)" npm package.